# PHP ldap_search 'Partial search results returned: Sizelimit exceeded'

Tags: php, search, ldap

This topic has been raised before, but none of the answers I've found have addressed this specific issue.

I have an openLDAP database containing records for students.  Currently there are around 50,000+ entries.

Using the following code I can get the `dn` for each entry and it works, it returns 50,000+ lines of output.

```
$cookie = '';
do {
    $result = ldap_search(
        $link, 'cn=students, cn=campus', '(id=*)', array('dn'), 1, 0, 0, LDAP_DEREF_NEVER,
        [['oid' => LDAP_CONTROL_PAGEDRESULTS, 'value' => ['size' => 2, 'cookie' => $cookie]]]
    );
    ldap_parse_result($link, $result, $errcode , $matcheddn , $errmsg , $referrals, $controls);
    
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($link, $result);
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        if ( isset ($entry['dn'] ) ) 
            echo "dn: "  .$entry['dn'] . "<br>";
    }
    if (isset($controls[LDAP_CONTROL_PAGEDRESULTS]['value']['cookie'])) {
        $cookie = $controls[LDAP_CONTROL_PAGEDRESULTS]['value']['cookie'];
    } else {
        $cookie = '';
    }
} while (!empty($cookie));
```

However I only want to return 250 entries, which entries to be retuned will be decided the search query entered. Currently this is `id=*`

I thought I could set the limit as:

```
$link, 'cn=students, cn=campus', '(id=*)', array('dn'), 1, 250, 0, LDAP_DEREF_NEVER,
```

But that then results in the error `Partial search results returned: Sizelimit exceeded`, even though what appears on screen does look correct.

Is the error output wrong, or is there a correct way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: The LDAP server has the last word on that number. Maybe its limit was set lower. What happens if you set the value to `3` instead of `250` ?

Comment: Setting to to 1 or 3 results in the same error. It's strange setting it to 0 allows 50,000+ records to be returned with no error, but I don't seem to be able to restrict that.

Comment: The error occurs when the count of fetched entries has reached the sizelimit while there are more results to fetch. It's just a way to inform you that a given query matches more entries than those returned (the same error happens when the number of entries exceeds the limit set on the server). In your case, since you expect that situation, you can catch ldap_search exceptions or silent them with the stfu operator, and check if something goes wrong or not with ldap_error().

Comment: Great thanks. It is strange it doesn't error when I don't set a limit.

Comment: There is no error when you set no limit because as you said all 50000+ entries are fetched in this case, without exceeding any sizelimit (the server has its own sizelimit).

Comment: Thanks. What confuses me is it can return 50000+ entries, but not a subset of them without getting the error.  If I can do 50000, why not 250 ?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your connection to LDAP v3:

```php
// Fixes ldap_search(): Partial search results returned: Sizelimit exceeded
// $link = ldap_connect($server_na);
ldap_set_option($link, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
// ldap_bind(..);
```

Saw that hint on the [LDAP Controls examples page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.examples-controls.php#126759).